# how to link nested C++ libraries in Cython

Tags: c++, cython, libraries

I am building a cython library to allow me to use a C++ library called Bar in python. 
My C++ library Bar relies on a second c++ library Foo.  however im having difficulty making this work in a cython project.
below is a description of my setup.

//Lib Foo -- is composed of a two files, and is a static library

```
foo.h:

foo.cpp
```

//lib Bar  is composed of two files, bar.h and bar.cpp, and is a dynamic library
lib B Imports lib a --I use Cmake and my CmakeLists file imports the static library foo.a

```
bar.h
#include "foo.h"
    class Bar {
        public:
            Bar();
            Foo foo;
```

Up to this point, my project bar works in a c++ environment.

In cython i create a bar class
cython pxd file:

```
cdef extern from "bar.h":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
        Bar() except +
```

in setup.py i do the following

```
setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
                [Extension(
                    "pyBar",
                     ["pyBar.pyx"],
                     language="c++",
                     libraries=["Bar"]
                )]
    ))
```

Cython builds fine, however when I import the cython built library into python and run it, 
my kernel restarts with no error.

If I remove the foo.h include from bar.h, then the cython library works fine in python.

My guess is that the cython library fails in python because the library cannot find foo.cpp or my foo.a library

I have made foo.h available locally in the python project.
I had assumed that because the lib Foo had been imported to Bar, and the foo.h header was available to cython, 
everything would work. but i seem to be missing something.

I think i need to make foo.cpp, or my foo library visible to cython too, but im not sure what i am missing
or how to fix it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the [Extending and embedding the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) chapter. Details are of course [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific, not the same on Linux and on Windows or MacOSX. Take also inspiration from *existing* similar code on [github](http://github.com/) or [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/). Be aware that [Python](http://python.org/) is open source: you are allowed to study its C and C++ source code.

Comment: **Without more details**, including some [mre] (and the mention of your OS, your C++ compiler, your compilation commands, your Python version) **your question is unclear**. Consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62228552/edit) it for improvement